# How can I obtain the authorization letter required to apply for a long-term D visa for a post-doc in Switzerland?

Tags: visa, working-visas, resident-permit, indian-citizens, switzerland

I have got a postdoc position in University of Basel and they have given the employment contract. In the swiss embassy page, to apply for visa they have asked to give authorization letter issued by the cantonal authority, passport and photos, biodata and visa fees. What is this authorization letter? Will I be getting the authorization letter from my employer? How is it normally done?

I found the documents required for applying visa in this page https://www.eda.admin.ch/.../documents-work-permits.html